# iAd not removing from view when receiving an error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iad, banner-ads

I have implemented the `bannerView didFailToReceiveAdWithError:` as such

```
- (void)bannerView(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    _bannerView.hidden = NO;
}
```

could you please let me know why it doesn't go away when the error is present please

i am getting this in the log:

```
2012-10-27 15:40:57.367 MinePedia[22467:11903] [AppDeveloper]: 
ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): 
Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable" 
UserInfo=0x7192530 {ADInternalErrorCode=3, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad inventory unavailable}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have `_bannerView.delegate = self;` after you create the instance of AdBannerView